# Vim imap jk <Esc> not working

Tags: linux, vim

In my vimrc, I've remapped jk to escape using imap.

The problem emerges when I use jk; it doesn't escape, it only echoes out `<Esc>`.

Here's the entry in quiestion:
`imap jk <Esc>`

It's also a good point to make that I'm also using vim-X11 in fedora.

Comment: Could you show us the entry in your vimrc?

Comment: `:imap jk <Esc>` works for me...

Comment: It's possible you have another mapping interfering. Try `inoremmap jk <esc>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your `'cpoptions'` settings contains `<`; then, special key codes like `<Esc>` are not recognized.

Find out where this got set via

```
:verbose set cpo?
```

or re-write the mapping to use a literal Escape character; enter it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>; it should appear as `^[` in the buffer.

---

PS: Though not related, you should usually use `:inoremap` unless remapping is required.

Comment: Thanks, the Ctrl + V thing worked ok! The set cpo? returned a menu file, though. Which line am I looking to edit in it to remove this problem?

Comment: Oh, `cpo` is saved and restored in many scripts, so it's a challenge. Binary search (i.e. disabling half of your scripts) may work, but maybe it's easier to just put `:set cpo-=<` above your mapping definition.

Comment: You, sir, are the freaking man! That worked perfectly which now means that `<Esc>` works just fine. Thanks for everything and happy solstice.

Comment: @JohnnyMcKenzie There is a way to force special meaning of `<Esc>` regardless of the value of `'cpoptions'`: `imap <special> jk <Esc>`.

Comment: @ZyX Thanks, I'll have to remember that one!

Answer (score 3):

For those who are here because of the title, the jk  mapping will also not work when `:set paste` is enabled.

Comment: Solved my problem