# Vim imap jk <Esc> not working even with escape character

Tags: vim, mapping

i read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704680/vim-imap-jk-esc-not-working) about mapping `<ESC>` key to `jk`. i tried the answer but nothing worked for me. these are i have tried in my vimrc:

```
inoremap jk <ESC>, inoremap jk <^[>, inoremap jk ^[, inoremap <special> jk <ESC
```

are they all wrong? i also tried setting cpo-=< above the mapping definition. and there is no comment after the  key

here is my [vimrc](https://github.com/shangsunset/dotefiles/blob/master/vimrc), the command is on the bottom of the file

im new in vim. thanks!

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Do other mappings (e.g. `inoremap hj FOO`) work? Also, try `:set nopaste`.

Comment: @IngoKarkat other mappings work, ive mapped keys for neoComplete and CtrlP. i tried `set nopaste`, and i cant paste those commands anymore. it still doesnt work when typing them by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

problem solved. the reason why `<esc>` doesnt work is because of this function in my vimrc:

```
if ! has("gui_running")
    set ttimeoutlen=10
    augroup FastEscape
        autocmd!
        au InsertEnter * set timeoutlen=0
        au InsertLeave * set timeoutlen=1000
    augroup END
endif
```

`inoremap jk <ESC>` works perfectly after getting rid of above function.

i guess its `augroup FastEscape` that makes `<esc>` mapping not working.

Comment: Thanks for this. This block was affecting my `inoremap`s as well. I was so frustrated as to why that was happening until I came across your answer. Many thanks!

Comment: @shangsunset @Tri Nguyen Thank you, super helpful. This led me to realize my issue as well. Alternatively, you could modify this line: `au InsertEnter * set timeoutlen=0` to be `au InsertEnter * set timeoutlen=200`. Found this based on [Ingo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829086/key-specific-timeoutlen-in-vim)

Answer (score 5):

`inoremap` is spelled wrong. (I also assume you put each of those on a separate line.) This should work.

```
inoremap <special> jk <ESC>
```

`<special>` forces `<ESC>` to be act as escape regardless of what `cpo` is set to.

Comment: you are right. i spelled it wrong but `inoremap` doesnt work either. i dont get any error messages. yea i only put one command at a time to try. are they correct or wrong?

Comment: @shangyeshen do you really have all three of those on the same line separated by commas? what is the output of `verbose inoremap jk`? How doesn't it work?

Comment: hi, the output is `i  jk   * <Esc>`. no i dont put them in one same line. hitting `jk` wont exit the insert mode

Comment: @shangyeshen well from the information you have provided the mapping should work. It might be some other configuration problem however I have no idea what it might be.

Comment: i see. does it help if you have a look at my vimrc? i put it in my question. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For those that are here because of the title, the jk  mapping will not work when `:set paste` is enabled.