# Key-specific timeoutlen in vim

Tags: vim

Is it possible to set a different `timeoutlen` depending on the typed key?

For example, I have this short timeout to go with my `<Esc>` remapping to `jk`

```
set timeoutlen=200
```

I'd like to make `timeoutlen` longer if I start with a `<leader>` because I have some mappings that require sequences of keys that are not as easy to type as `jk`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's nothing built-in. With regards to your mapping, you probably mean `:inoremap jj <Esc>`, and for that to apply quickly, you just need to ensure that there are no other insert mode mappings that **start with** `jj`. To avoid that the first `j` appears only with a delay, you *could* use `:autocmds` to toggle the `'timeoutlen'` value:

```
:autocmd InsertEnter * set timeoutlen=200
:autocmd InsertLeave * set timeoutlen=1000
```

Comment: So what it basically does, it sets separate timeoutlenghts for insert and other modes, am I right? My only mappings starting with `j` are `:inoremap jk <Esc>` and `:inoremap jj <Esc>A;<Esc>`. This are the only mappings I have for insert mode, the rest is for normal or visual.

Comment: Yes, that's right. With the autocmds, the delay until the `j` appears should be smaller.

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by Ingo Karkat will affect all insert mode mappings, so it may break plugins that define other insert mode mappings that are hard to type in so short a time period.

In order to escape from insert mode without lagging, I have found a smarter way, which leads to plugin [better-escape.vim](https://github.com/jdhao/better-escape.vim).

The default shortcut to escape insert mode is `jk`, you can change it via the following option:

```
let g:better_escape_shortcut = 'jj'
```

It will calculate the time interval between pressing the first char and the second char in the shortcut (the default is 150 ms). If you press those two chars quickly, you will leave insert mode. Otherwise, the characters will be written literally. To adjust the time interval, use the following option:

```
let g:better_escape_interval = 200
```